# How do you count loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

How do you count within a loop to show what loop you are on?

```
Individual.all.each do |f|

    #Fetch Data
    Puts Count

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `each_with_index` instead of `each`, which will allow you to use a 2nd item inside the block.

```
Individual.all.each_with_index do |f, index|
  puts f # show the 'individual'
  puts index # show 'which one'
end
```

Remember that all indexes start at `0` so you will need to do `puts index + 1` if you're wanting to show the 'number' of the one you're on (because if you're on the `3rd` item the index will be `2`).

Comment: Thanks!  A quick question (sort of related); is there a way timing each loop and providing a cumulative at each loop?  (Loop 1 takes 1sec Puts 1sec > Loop 2  takes 1sec Puts 2sec > Loop 3  takes 1sec Puts 3sec)

Comment: Sounds like a new question to me :) Create a question with that in it and you can link to it from here...

Comment: could also use `each.with_index(1)` -> `puts index` instead of `puts index + 1` if you need it to start at 1 instead of zero

Comment: @jimbob yes, you can subtract times in ruby like... x = Time.now; y = Time.now; y - x. So you would initialize a counter above like `total = 0` and then inside the loop at the top you would initialize `start = Time.now' then at the end you can do 'end = Time.now; total = total + (end - start)`